# Set up Logitech K380 for Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, keyboard, bluetooth, logitech

I have just installed on my SSD new OS Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I of course tried to set-up my Logitech K380 keyboard on my new Linux.

Well. Yesterday I kind read a lot of pages about that, how to get all those settings in, but I didn't a thing.

So, can someone please explain from A-Z how to set-up Logitech K380 on Linux 16.04 LTS?

Answer (score 8):

I have a Logitech K480.

First put the keyboard into pairing mode using the manual for instructions

Open bluetooth manager and press on the "+" to add a device

Bluetooth manager should find a device with name Logitech K380, click on Logitech K380 and then next.  You should be prompted to type a PIN in on the bluetooth keyboard, enter the PIN followed by the Enter button and you should be connected

Comment: @Didzkins did this method work? the OP should have accepted this answer if it did, or made a comment if it didn't

Comment: I found the solution in Logitech forum https://community.logitech.com/s/question/0D55A00006uu6qVSAQ/k380-incorrect-pin-unable-to-pair. In short, press the Backspace, enter the code displayed on screen and press enter.

Answer (score -3):

I deleted `~/.config/pulse`

And it worked. Found the solution on [this Arch forum thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=195886&p=2)

Comment: pulse is a sound config tool. The thread mentioned is case for wireless headphones.

Comment: It's a keyboard btw